# What is up with g++, valarray and auto?

Tags: c++

The following code runs fine with cl.exe (produces the expected output 2, 9.9).

With g++ it produces no output at all with -O3 optimisation and the wrong output (1,10) with -O1 and -O2 optimisation.

The version of g++ is 12.2.0, run from the command window in Windows 10.

Do I have the wrong expectations of auto and valarray, or am I just doing something stupid?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <valarray>

int main()
{
   double dx = 0.1;
   std::valarray<double> Y{ 1.0, 10.0 };

   // Works fine with g++, all optimisation levels
// std::valarray<double> dY1 = dx * std::valarray<double>{ Y[1], -Y[0] };
// Y += dY1;

   // Fails completely with g++ -O3; gives wrong answer with -O1 and -O2; works fine with cl.exe
   auto                  dY2 = dx * std::valarray<double>{ Y[1], -Y[0] };
   Y += dY2;

   std::cout << Y[0] << '\t' << Y[1] << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I don't see anything in the standard detailing how the validity of `std::valarray` replacement types for expression templates should relate to the lifetime of the inputs of the operations. So it isn't clear to me whether what exactly should be UB or should be allowed, but at least it seems very unlikely that the validity of the replacement type should extend beyond the lifetime of the temporary object.

Comment: g++ certainly didn't like the auto. I also found that if I removed the dx* then things were OK. But I'm beginning to get very wary about relying on "auto" at all.

Comment: `std::valarray` is from a time before `auto`, so it never accounted for this kind of use. I think it is very rarely used any more.

Comment: Ah, @user17732522, I grew up on Fortran, where the default array operations behave very like valarray. The ability to write whole-container elemental operations as just A=B+C and D=sin(E*x) is not to be sniffed at.

Comment: Have a look at libraries like Eigen for that use case. They are much more sophisticated.

Comment: `auto` here will be a `std::__1::__val_expr<std::__1::_BinaryOp<std::__1::multiplies<double>, std::__1::__scalar_expr<double>, std::__1::valarray<double>>>`, which is an expression that refers to a dangling temporary.  That's part of the ... *charm* ... of `std::valarray`.  In my opinion, `std::valarray` wasn't as well vetted by the standards subcommittee that dealt with it as they should have been — I think they ran out of steam.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

libstdc++ uses expression templates to implement valarray operations.

This is so things like `X = 3 * Y + 2` can be implemented as a single loop instead of one loop multiplying by 3 then another one adding 2.

However, these expression templates store references to their operands. Your `std::valarray<double>{ Y[1], -Y[0] }` is a temporary, so it immediately becomes a dangling reference.

Copying to a real `std::valarray<double>` would actually evaluate the expression template before the temporary dies. You can also see that this works if you don't use a temporary:

```cpp
auto not_a_temporary = std::valarray<double>{ Y[1], -Y[0] };
auto dY2 = dx * not_a_temporary;
```

Comment: fwiw, according to cppreference all operators of `std::valarray<T>` just return `std::valarray<T>` https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/valarray/operator_arith3, and afaik introduction of `std::valarray` predates the invention of expression templates. So this isnt actually conforming, is it?

Comment: Thank-you, @Artyer, for your answer. But it will make me very wary of using "auto" in future. I'm not sufficiently competent with the standard to judge whether this is really the expected behaviour - it was certainly a nasty shock to me.

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai The cppreference page actually mentions that "The function can be implemented with the return type different from std::valarray."

Comment: @463035818_is_not_an_ai No, `valarray` is explicitly designed as expression template. All functions of `valarray` that are specified to return a `valarray` may return a replacement type instead for exactly that purpose. See https://eel.is/c++draft/numarray#valarray.syn-3. That's basically the only reason to use valarray.